# Algorithm to split a graph into disconnected subgraphs of <=N nodes, challenge is to obtain the maximum number of subgraphs (networkx, python)

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I am wondering if there is an algorithm to split a large graph/network into multiple disconnected networks of up to N nodes; where you'd like to achieve as many disconnected networks as possible? If not, how would you code this in python/networkx?

In other words, suppose I have a large interconnected network of 1000 nodes, I would like to delete as little nodes as possible, in order to obtain  subgraphs of up to 10 nodes (as many as possible).

Comment: So you are going to remove edges from the network? Otherwise I don't see how you can make two connected subgraphs less connected.

Comment: I would like to remove nodes with their  edges, to make the network less connected.

Comment: u can use community detection then separate communies. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/louvain/

Answer (score 0):

Some bad news: This is a generalisation of [Independent Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)), which is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).  (The Independent Set problem is usually framed as *keeping* a subset of vertices, but it amounts to the same thing as your problem with n fixed at 1.)  That means it's very unlikely that a polynomial-time algorithm exists that can solve this problem exactly.